# Looping Through Multiple Variables

Tags: python, loops, variables, pyqt

I'm creating a Python app with PyQt Gui. Basically I have multiple LineEdits with variable names like

```
Line_1 = 'x'
Line_2 = 'y'
Line_3 = 'z'
...
Line_15 = '0'
```

I wan't to create a loop through them at once like

```
for i in range(1, 15):
    self.Line_{0}.format(i).setEnabled(False)
```

but i couldn't manage to do it

Comment: a dictionary job?

Comment: i converted .ui file with pyuic to .py. All of the Line_X variables are created separately so at this point i don't know how i should convert them since i'm a beginner and i have almost 100 variables need to be enabled/disabled upon choice of the user

Comment: Please continue with whatever tutorial you're using and pay special attention to the part about lists and other data structures.

Comment: @fuzunspm. `getattr(self, 'Line_{0}'.format(i)).setEnabled(False)`.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using variable names with numbers on the end when you should be using a `list` or a `dict` for the job.